# Problema al publicar app en Play Store

Tags: android

Al subir una abb a Play Store me dicen que falta la firma.
Hice la APK con book2 a partir de un PDF pues no sé programar. Me la dieron en APK y la convertí en aab por medio de una aplicación gratuita de Play Store pero no tiene firma, no la admiten y no sé cómo ponerle la firma.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Una APK la puedes crear de dos formas: con firma y sin firma (para pruebas, por ejemplo). Para subirla a la Play Store es obligatorio que esté firmada. Aquí tienes un enlace de cómo se haría desde Android Studio: [Enlace Documentación Oficial para firmar App](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing?hl=es-419) Ten en cuenta que al firmar una APK, te genera un archivo/llave .jks, que es único y asociado a la APK. Y cada vez que subas un APK a la Play Store te solicitará previamente que demuestres que eres el propietario con el .jks Suerte!

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido, comentas: "no la admiten y no sé cómo ponerle la firma.", primeramente trata de firmarla, revisa la documentación, https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing?hl=es-419 , puedes agregar lo que trataste o investigaste en tu pregunta por favor, si tienes problemas comentalos en la misma. Recuerda revisar [ask], saludos.